# How to get the current inner window size in an Adobe AIR app?

Tags: flash, air

I need to know the available screen space in my current AIR app, but when I use `stage.nativeWindow.width` and `stage.nativeWindow.height`, I get the size of the window **including** the title bar. I'd like to know the "inner size", so excluding the title bar. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [stage.stageWidth](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#stageWidth) and [stage.stageHeight](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#stageHeight) are what you are looking for ?